# Working gnu-screen alternative for WSL-minecraftserver

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to launch my minecraft server on SSH on WSL (Ubuntu 18.04) on Windows.

The way I plan to do it with a phone or something: Connect to vpn, then ssh into windows, then type wsl (works fine), and finally open a session (for example screen) and launch the script for the minecraft server in there.

The problem is, when I finally get into launching the script and detaching the screen and close the ssh connection, the screen will close after some time automatically. WSL says it was terminated. I dont know what to do.

I should also add that the script should run permanently. The mc server is running on java and constantly gives output. So I want it to be available all the time.

Comment: I recommend using [Linux Game Server Managers](https://linuxgsm.com/lgsm/mcserver/) setup which will automatically configure tmux to run your server in a separate virtual terminal and also makes management much easier.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you for your answer, the tool suits perfectly in my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

linuxgsm.com is a Server manager that is also available for minecraft, it uses tmux and is a perfect alternative with many other features.

Comment: Does this solve the problem? If so then can you provide a script for OP to use?

Comment: On the website you can head to the tab minecraft and install the server. The setup cant be easier, no script needed.